# Change the 'Product Identifier' to another attribute in dataflow import profile

Tags: magento-1.9

Unfortunately I have to use the dataflow profile in Magento (1.9.2.1) to update some prices. The problem is I have to use another attribute as the product identifier instead of the SKU.

Any ideas how can this be done?